# how can I configure an actionbar to show a progressbar in each long process?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-actionbar, fragment, viewstub

I want to have a methond or something in my action bar, for showing a progress bar indeterminate each time I need to do a long process. 
I had been trying with a ViewStub, I thought also about using a frameLayout and a fragment, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Activity#setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility%28boolean%29).

```
// This has to be called before setContentView
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

// This shows an indeterminate progress bar in the action bar
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

- Put a ProgressBar view in the action bar.
- Run the long task as an AsyncTask.
- Use the PublishProgress method during the long task to indicate how much work has been done so far.
- Use OnProgressUpdate callback to update the ProgressBar.